Topologizing quasi orders with regards to products
This morning I was asked by a colleague for the "right" way to construct a topology on a quasi-order (aka preorder, a reflexive and transitive relation) such that the topology on a product of quasi-orders coincides with the product topology on their quasi-ordered topological spaces (and of course, is compatible with the usual linearly ordered topology when the order is a linear order).
My understanding (e.g. Ward 1954) is that the space generated by the subbasis $\{Q\setminus(\leftarrow,q]:q\in Q\}\cup\{Q\setminus[q,\rightarrow):q\in Q\}$ is a reasonable topologization of a quasi-order; note that when $Q$ is linear, this is equal to the standard subbasis $\{(q,\rightarrow):q\in Q\}\cup\{(\leftarrow,q):q\in Q\}$ for a linearly ordered topological space. So in the topological product $Q_0\times Q_1$, we have basic open sets e.g. $(Q_0\setminus(\leftarrow,q_0])\times(Q_1\setminus(\leftarrow,q_1])$.
But now, let's define the product of quasi-orders $Q_0\times Q_1$ to be $\langle p_0,p_1\rangle \leq \langle q_0,q_1\rangle$ if and only if $p_0\leq q_0$ and $p_1\leq q_1$. Then we'd have a basic open set of the form $(Q_0\times Q_1)\setminus(\leftarrow,\langle q_0,q_1\rangle]$.
If our coffee hasn't quite kicked in yet, maybe we'd think these sets are the same. But suppose now that $Q_0=Q_1=\mathbb R$ and $q_0=q_1=0$. Then we have $(Q_0\setminus(\leftarrow,q_0])\times(Q_1\setminus(\leftarrow,q_1])=(0,\infty)^2$, but $(Q_0\times Q_1)\setminus(\leftarrow,\langle q_0,q_1\rangle]=\mathbb R^2\setminus(-\infty,\vec 0]^2$. So it seems we're generating a somewhat coarser topology if we first cast to the partial order and then generate a topology, versus casting to topologies and then considering the product topology.
Which leads to my question: am I overlooking something in my argument above? And if not, is there another subbasis generated by a quasi-order that produces the standard topology for linear orders, that is compatible with both order products and topological products?

Somewhat of an aside: I do think this process works for orders with a minimum $0_Q$ and maximum $1_Q$. Then we may show that e.g. $$(Q_0\setminus(\leftarrow,q_0])\times(Q_1\setminus(\leftarrow,q_1])=(Q_0\times Q_1)\setminus(\leftarrow,\langle q_0,1_{Q_1}\rangle]\cap(Q_0\times Q_1)\setminus(\leftarrow,\langle 1_{Q_0},q_1\rangle].$$

A long time ago I was looking at intrinsic topologies for ordered structures and I came across a paper by Jimmie Lawson that catalogued all kinds of topologies that could be defined intrinsically on (semi)lattices. Here are links to reviews on zbMath of that paper and a related one. The latter shows that the topology of a compact topological (semi)lattice is intrinsic and unique. You'll see there's many ways to topologise a (semi)lattice; some of the ways work on partial/quasi-orders as well.
